# Regarding quality of different k-means algorithms

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, k-means

I see that for k-means, we have Lloyd's algorithm, Elkan's algorithm, and we also have hierarchical version of k-means.

For all these algorithms, I see that Elkan's algorithm could provide a boost in term of speed. But what I want to know, is the quality from all these k-means algorithms. Each time, we run these algorithms, the result would be different, due to their heuristic and probabilistic nature. Now, my question is, when it comes to clustering algorithm like k-means, if we want to have a better quality result (as in lesser distortion, etc.) between all these k-means algorithms, which algorithm would be able to give you the better quality? Is it possible to measure such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better solution is usually one that has a better (lower) `J(x,c)` value, where:

```
J(x,c) = 1/|x| * Sum(distance(x(i),c(centroid(i)))) for each i in [1,|x|]
```

**Wherre:**

- `x` is the list of samples
- `|x|` is the size of `x` (number of elements)
- `[1,|x|]` all the numbers from 1 to `|x|` (inclusive)
- `c` is the list of centroids (or means) of clusters (i.e., for `k` clusters |c| = k)
- `distance(a,b)` (sometimes denoted as ||a-b|| is the distance between "point" a to "point" b (In euclidean 2D space it is `sqrt((a.x-b.x)^2 + (a.y-b.y)^2)`)
- centroid(i) - the centroid/mean which is closest to `x(i)`

Note that this approach does not require switching to supervised technique and can be fully automated!

Comment: Note that since a lot of methods for finding the solutions start with randomised initialisations, which can radically affect the quality of the solution, it's worth taking the average (and variance) of this over a moderate number of runs to determine accurate efficacy

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you need some data with labels to cross-validate you clustering algorithm.

Comment: clustering is *unsupervised* learning technique, what cross validation exactly are you talking about? you don't know the ground truth of the labels, it is not supervised classification problem.

Comment: You can always mark some data by hand, run clustering algorithm on that data and than compare original labels to algorithm output.

Comment: Then it is called *test set* and *train set*, not cross validation. It is also not the solution, because this is not meant to evaluate how good the algorithm is on the general case (as per my understanding of the problem), it is meant to chose the best cluster for the specific problem, since the clustering algorithms are heurisitcal, so two runs might generate different results, and you need to chose for this specific instance - which is better.

Answer (score 1):

How about the pathological case of the two-moons dataset? unsupervised k-means will fail badly. A high quality method I am aware of employs a more probabilistic approach using mutual information and combinatorial optimization. Basically you cast the clustering problem as the problem of finding the optimal [cluster] subset of the full point-set for the case of two clusters.

You can find the [relevant paper here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6453v1.pdf) (page 42) and the corresponding [Matlab code here](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/submodular/) to play with (checkout the two-moons case). If you are interested in a C++ high-performance implementation of that with a speed up of >30x then you can find it [here HPSFO](http://hpsfo.bitbucket.org).

Comment: Though informative, it does not answer the question: `between all these k-means algorithms, which algorithm would be able to give you the better quality? Is it possible to measure such thing?`

Answer (score 0):

To compare the quality, you should have a labeled dataset and measure the results by some criteria like [NMI](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html)